# How to calculate gradient of output of a neural network w.r.t an input?

Tags: python, pytorch

I would like to calculate the partial derivative of (num1 * output1, num1 * output2) w.r.t. num1. The input of the neural network is (num1, 2, 3, 4). The expected dim of the output is 2. Is there a way to do that?

```
number_of_inputs = 4
hidden_layer = 64
number_of_outputs = 2

class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(number_of_inputs,hidden_layer)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(hidden_layer,number_of_outputs)

        self.activation = nn.Tanh()

    def forward(self, x):
        output = self.linear1(x)
        output = self.activation(output)
        output = self.linear2(output)

        return output

a = NeuralNetwork()

# a(input1, input2, input3, input4) -> (output1, output2)

num1 = torch.tensor(1, dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=True)
b = a(torch.tensor([num1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=True))
```

Comment: If the question is not clear please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: Is the derivative not simply `(output1, output2)`?

Comment: num1 is part of the input.

Comment: are `output1` and `output2` completely independent of `num1` ?

Comment: outpu1, outpu2 is the output of a(num1, input2, input3, input4)